# missing java package ome.units

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Sorry I'm completely new to java. 
A java file referenced ome.units.UNITS, when I loaded the file I had warning "package ome.units" doesn't exist.
I'm curious, does the package ome.units belong to system or user implementation?
I googled ome.units but had no luck to find any helpful info.

Comment: A search for `package ome.units java` finds several relevant results *very* quickly. Most importantly: https://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/ome-model/ome-xml/java-library.html

Comment: Maven Central is another great tool to track down dependencies: Looks like the group is [***org.openmicroscopy***](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|ome)

Comment: Jon Skeet, the link you gave is for ome.xml which is not ome.units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include/import the following dependency as Jon Skeet pointed out:

The `ome-xml` project contains the package `ome.units`.

You have a couple options…

#### Maven

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openmicroscopy</groupId>
    <artifactId>ome-xml</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

```java
compile 'org.openmicroscopy:ome-xml:5.3.1'
```

#### Download

1. ↓ [Open Microscopy | Support | ome-xml | Download](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/ome-model/ome-xml/java-library.html#download)
2. ↓ [Open Microscopy | Bio Formats 5.2.4](http://downloads.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.2.4/)
3. ↓ **Bio-Formats components downloads**
4. **OME-XML Java library** | [ome-xml.jar](http://downloads.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.2.4/artifacts/ome-xml.jar)

Here is the source code [via GitHub](https://github.com/ome/ome-model/blob/master/ome-xml/src/main/java/ome/units/UNITS.java).

Comment: Thanks for your help!